# linux C string to int

Tags: c, linux, strtol

I'm trying to convert this string `"09195462965"` to an int but I'm running into problems.

snippet of my code:

```
int n, p, pnum=0;
char buffer[256];
char *endptr;
long pnumber;

bzero(buffer,256);
p = read(sock,buffer,255);

    pnumber = strtol(buffer, &endptr, pnum);

printf("n: %ld",pnumber);

p = write(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

A client sends a string of `"09195462965"` then the server receives it.

Now on the server that string must be turned into an `int` i.e. `09195462965`.

Note: the server sends the number as string.

Comment: i don't think the maximum size of int is larger than  09195462965.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `strtol()` incorrectly, the last parameter should be the base that you want. For example if you want to store that number in base 10 (decimal):

```
long pnumber;
pnumber = strtol("09195462965", NULL, 10); //nst char *nptr is "09195462965"
                                           //char **endptr  is null
                                           //int base       is 10 for decimal
printf("n: %ld",pnumber);

>> 9195462965
```

Make sure you read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for the function you're using.

Passing `pnum` (which is set to `0`) as your doing for the last parameter is causing it to spit back "0", because of the number you're passing in.

09195462965 has digits from 0-9 (so I assume you wanted dec) if you pass in "0" to `strtol()` then it's going to see that first `0` and will treat the number has octal, the problem with that is that octal numbers go from 0-7, thus the 9's are "out of bounds" for an octal number and as such `strtol()` spits back 0.

with a number like: `07175462765`, you'd be fine to pass in `pnum` when it's 0.

Comment: *If  the  value  of base is  zero,  the  expected  form  of  the  subject  sequence  is  that  of  an integer constant as described in [...]* So `base = 0` might be what the op is after, if the number is to be interpreted as octal. I only added the quote because you posted in your answer ***make sure you read the man page...*** ;)

Comment: @cnicutar - oh no worries there, I just didn't both to explain *why* that string was invalid with `pnum=0`, as I assumed OP would read the man page and figure it out. ;)  But I updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

That's too big to fit in an `int`. Try `strtoumax` and store it in an `uintmax_t`.

```
uintmax_t pnumber = strtoumax(buffer, &endptr, 10);
if (pnumber == UINTMAX_MAX && errno == ERANGE)
    /* Too big. */
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `strtoumax` you can try `strtoull` et al.